# Algolia set master index for a slave

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I have 2 indices named `items_au` and `items_us`

I created these two indices using `public $indices = ['items_au', 'items_us'];`

In my `algoliaSettings` I am creating 3 `slaves` for each `index`:

```
public static $perEnvironment = true;

public $algoliaSettings = [
  'slaves' => [
        'items_au_by_price_asc',
        'items_au_by_price_desc',
        'items_au_by_views',

        'items_us_by_price_asc',
        'items_us_by_price_desc',
        'items_us_by_views'
    ]
]
```

I wanted the `master index` of indices starting with `items_au` to be `items_au_local` and the others to reference `items_us_local`.

Currently, all the slaves have `items_au_local` as their master slave. 
I tried using `masterIndex` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

The extension is not able to handle that.
The easiest would be to handle slaves via the api client directly by doing a setSettings call for both items_us and items_au

Comment: I agree with @max. You should fire query on slave itself.